# How do I install latest font-manager?

Tags: software-installation, fonts, font-manager

I wanted to install font-manager on my Ubuntu 16.04. I used [font-manager staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~font-manager/+archive/ubuntu/staging) to install the latest version. But it gives me an error after installation. The error mentioned "symbol lookup error".

Now I want to install it from source. How do I install it?

Comment: Did you try the [zesty version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/font-manager)?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I didn't try. But I tried the one with latest version from PPA. Version is `0.7.3~201610161850~ubuntu16.04.1`. Probably latest

Comment: Ok. I just tried `font-manager 0.7.3-1` on 16.10 without encountering the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First download the latest release archive from [Font-manager github release page](https://github.com/FontManager/master/releases).
2. Then extract the downloaded archive. If the filename is `font-manager-0.7.3.tar.bz2`, you can use `tar xvf font-manager-0.7.3.tar.bz2` to extract it.
3. Then install these development packages required to build it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential valac libjson-glib-dev libgree-dev libgree-0.8-dev libgucharmap-2-90-dev libsqlite3-dev libgirepository1.0-dev
   ```

   - (Optional) If you use file-browser integration, you also need these packages

     - For nautilus - `python-nautilus` package
     - For thunar - `thunar-python` package
   - (Optional) If you want to be able to use archive support, you need to have `file-roller` installed (Which comes with Ubuntu by default).
4. Then use this command to configure while you're in the root of the source

   ```
   ./configure
   ```

   Optionally, if you want to enable installation from archives, you can use `--with-file-roller` option to `configure` command. In that case, you should have file-roller installed.

   Also you can enable file-browser integration for nautilus or thunar.

   So, for nautilus integreation and archive support, I'd use

   ```
   ./configure --with-file-roller --with-nautilus --with-thunarx
   ```

   (Yes, it's `thunarx`, not `thunar`)

   After the configuration is finished, you'll be given a confirmation like this

   ```
   Font Manager 0.7.3

   C compiler:             gcc
   Vala compiler:          /usr/bin/valac
   Installation prefix:    /usr/local
   Archive Support:        yes
   File Browser Support:   yes
   ```
5. Then use `make` and `make install` command

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

That should successfully install the font-manager
.

You can also use `sudo checkinstall` instead of the last command. That will create a deb file of the application and you can later remove it using this command. Also you can reuse the deb filw without doing all these steps again.

```
sudo dpkg -r font-manager
```

(Thanks to muru for noting this)

**Update**

Check the FontManager author's [answer][auth_ans] for easier method to build a deb package.

Comment: If you found any problem with the instruction here, please drop a comment here.

Comment: Use `checkinstall` instead of just `make install` so that you can remove this later: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

Answer (score 1):

@Anwar  - Nice, thanks.

Another option that *should* work on Ubuntu systems is building a debian package from master.

```
git clone https://github.com/FontManager/master.git
cd master/build-aux
make deb
```

HTH

Comment: Ah! FontManager author here! Great addition. Many thanks :)